# JavaFX AnimationTimer is doing more then 60 updates per second

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having an issue with the AnimationTimer from JavaFX. After doing some research it appears that others also have that issue.

The AnimationTimer is not doing 60 frames per second. I'm having a 144hz monitor and thus my refresh rate is at 144hz, the AnimationTimer is now arround 143/144 fps. If I set my refresh rate to 60hz it will do arround 60 fps again.

Even worse on my Laptop running Ubuntu, the AnimationTimer is for some reason doing 300-500 fps there.

Is there any way to make the AnimationTimer do 60 FPS, or if that is not possible how would I archive a 60 FPS loop in javafx.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone finds this via the Google search in the future and the bug is still not fixed.

http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx

This will help you with a game loop that runs on a constant frame rate.

Comment: Got a server down message when I clicked the link.

Comment: Luckily it has been catched by the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190215171815/svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different threads on this, so I encourage anyone arriving here to keep looking.

This [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8211059) seems to pertain.

I did the following, as a stop gap measure. IDK if it really "solves" anything. Seems like the potential is there for a considerable number of spins through the handle() method, consuming cpu.

```
// instance variable
private long previousTimestamp;
private long nanoSecsPerFrame = Math.round(1.0/60 * 1e9);

// handle method
public void handle(long timeStamp)
{
    if (timeStamp - prevTimeStamp < nanoSecsPerFrame)
    {
        return;
    }
    prevTimeStamp = timeStamp;

    // your code
}
```

I have this problem with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04's repository java-8-openjdk-amd64.

`AnimatinTimer` works fine on Windows 10 using either OpenJDK 11 with OpenJFX 11 or just using pre-modular OpenJDX8. I'm hoping that switching to modular Java/JavaFX on Ubuntu will fix this.